# Checked values(names) from listview to another activity

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

In my app I have some names(from mysql database) in listview there are 100 names corresponding with checkbox. Once I click on noe or more checkbox then corresponding name should be displayed in next activity listview.
How to do this? If anybody have codes please provide me.
I would be appreciated your help..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: No sir.. if u have anything related about this pls provide me..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you've created your List with simple adapter like this:

```
ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(MyActivity.this,arraylist,R.layout.list_item,new String[]{"name"},new int[]{R.id.txtName});
            MyActivity.this.setListAdapter(adapter);
```

To pass "name" to second activity you can do this:

```
        final ListView lv = MyActivity.this.getListView();      
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>parent, View view, int position, long id){
                HashMap<String, String>hm = (HashMap<String, String>)lv.getItemAtPosition(position);                    
                String message=hm.get("name").toString();
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                in.putExtra("nameToSend", message);

                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
```

Then in second activity you can catch name like this:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.second_layout);
                Intent in = getIntent();
        String name = in.getStringExtra("nameToSend");
....



    }
```

Comment: Hi sir.. When i click the checkox checked names should have to pass to next activity listview..

Comment: Oh, sorry I thought that you want to pass FROM listview to second activity

Comment: Its k sir.. pls provide the code for above said. I have stored names in arraylist and displayed those are in ActivityA list with checkbox when i click the checkbox then checked name should be displayed in ActivityB listview

Comment: I've found a solution for you on this page:     http://www.mysamplecode.com/2012/07/android-listview-checkbox-example.html                                           Pay attention to this sentence:" To find out what all checkboxes are selected just loop thru the ArrayList that is being maintained by listening to the onClick event for the checkbox"

Comment: K sir I will try this.. this one i needed I have seen it now.. I will modify it as my requirements.. Thanks for your quick response..